# What is micronaut's alternative for "JpaSpecificationExecutor"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, micronaut, micronaut-data

I want dynamic filter queries. Example

/api/users?name=xyz

/api/users?name=xyz&email=abc

With spring boot it was possible using JpaSpecificationExecutor, where I could pass custom "Specification". How to do this using micronaut-data?

Comment: create an repository like that (https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#repositories) and build the query using the entity manager and JPA criteria API

Comment: Yes, did the same.. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use similar classes with *Micronout Data*'s [JPA specifications](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#specifications).

> Based on the same concept as Spring Data, when you need to create queries dynamically by composing JPA criteria then you can implement the **`JpaSpecificationExecutor`** interface which provides multiple methods that receive an instance of **`Specification`** which can be used in combination with existing repository interfaces.

Comment: Usually such link-only suggestions can be placed as comment. I added proper formatting plus highlighted same JPA-related classes to make this a easy to read and helpful answer.

Comment: Looks like this was added to Micronaut data recently. When I had asked this question, this was not supported! Thanks for the answer!